# Using logged in user to find related models in Django

Tags: django, generics, view

I'm lost :(

I am still trying to learn Django, and have decided to go ahead and just use class-based views because function-based views are being deprecated.  I made function based views and seem to be able to navigate them without much issue.  I can move the request around and get user info etc.

As it stands right now I've built some models that relate to User but I can't seem to get these into my generic views based on the logged in user.

---

Existing models:

```
class Common(models.Model):
    "User abstraction for carrying general info."
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")
    ...some methods/properties...
```

```
class Employee(Common):
    "Employee specific info."
    ...some methods/properties...
```

---

What I'm trying to do in my views is check the logged in user and pull the corresponding Employee.

My current view looks like this:

```
class v_UserDetail(DetailView):
    # model = Employee
    template_name = "user.html"

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(User, self.request.user)
```

I expect I should be able to do something to the affect of `Employee.user.get_object(id='')` but I have no idea how to get the logged in user's ID.

Now it may be that I don't have enough experience with Django to dive right into class views, but I am just lost.  I've been pouring over documentation and tutorials and they all seem to expect me to already understand what is being passed into the generic views.

Note:  I am running Django 1.6 on Python 2.7

**RESOLVED**
Thanks to the comment from @karthikr below I was able to make a tiny tweak and get it running.  The new view is:

```
class v_UserDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = "user.html"

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Employee, id = self.request.user.id)
```

I will now how to edit the get_object function to check for other related classes, but this gets me where I wanted to be.  I can pull other objects based exclusively on the logged in user.

**IMPROVED**
I've found that I was making this WAY harder than was necessary.  The user object carries it's capacity to pull it's related models into the template, so I've dropped the object finding from view all together.  The new template has this:

```
 {% if user.employee %}
            {% include 'employee/emp_profile.html' %}
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Before I post it as an answer, is there are reason you're not just using a [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) for the Employee model?

Comment: Function based views are not being deprecated. Function based _generic_ views will be.

Comment: Try this: `get_object_or_404(User, id = self.request.user.id)`

Comment: @cms_mgr I am, was a mistake in my copy pasta.  It's been edited already.

Comment: what @RobL says is true, though don't let this put you off using class-based views :) They're great.

Comment: Two questions. Do all Employee's have a corresponding user, without fail? Should only the logged in user be able to see their Employee page?

Comment: @cms_mgr Yes and yes. I don't want slugs/PKs in the URL.  That would have made this infinitely easier. So ONLY the logged in user can see ONLY THEIR info. (Think profile page with links to other employee related items.)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you right, you want to set view model according to user info. Try it this way:

```
class v_UserDetail(DetailView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(v_UserDetail, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if request.user.common_set: # change common_set according to your related_name
            self.model = Common
        if request.user.employee_set:
            self.model = Employee
```

Comment: While this doesn't answer the specific question I had it does point in a direction to continue.  Thanks!  I probably should have mentioned that common is meta abstract.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `pk` in the URL while still retaining the privacy you want. Just use a normal DetailView like:

```
class PersonDetailView(DeatilView):
    model = Employee
    context_object_name = "employee"
    template_name_suffix = "_detail"
```

And in your template something like:

```
{% if request.user == employee.user %}
Show user content
{% else %}
Show message to say you're not allowed to see this
{% endif %}
```

You should also look at [django-braces](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.2/), which makes redirecting to and from login pages for logged out users much simpler. For example, you could update the view above to look like:

```
class PersonDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeatilView):
    model = Employee
    context_object_name = "employee"
    template_name_suffix = "_detail"
    login_url = "your_login_url"
```

and it will redirect logged-in users to the login page and return them to the Employee detail once they authenticate.